# Voice command to remove all characters delimited by a given character in Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: windows, dragon-naturally-speaking

Is there a voice command to remove all characters delimited by a given characters in Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

For example, given the string 
`ax.set_xlabel('Number of computed F1-scores', fontsize=fontsize)` and assuming that the mouse cursor is placed on between the `p` and the `u` in `computed`, I would like the voice command to transform the string into `ax.set_xlabel('', fontsize=fontsize)`.

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.